# AWS SNS push messaging, how to send message to mobile user based on custom tag, attribute like email id or user-id?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mobile, push-notification, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

If I have devices register with AWS SNS can I also add some custom fields like email ID, user ID? Then later can I send message to the notification hub using that custom field. Like I approach ( I means the server app) to AWS SNS and send the message “Hello User1” to the device with email field has value “user1@abc.com” . And then SNS would find out your devices (if you have many registered for the app) and then send the message “Hello User1” to all your devices.

I can see that Windows Azure cloud supports this feature using tags.
E.g: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn530749.aspx

See the "using tags to target users" section in the above link and below figure.

I am not able to see this feature in AWS SNS mobile push notifications. The topics in SNS just provides subscription model there is no filtering based on some value.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

The best way to achieve that would be utilize [custom user data option](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMessageAttributes.html) for the endpoints: *"Amazon Simple Notification Service (Amazon SNS) provides support for delivery of message attributes to Amazon SQS endpoints. Message attributes allow you to provide structured metadata items (such as timestamps, geospatial data, signatures, and identifiers) about the message"*.

The custom user data can be set during devices registrations, or you can use [SetEndpointAttributes API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_SetEndpointAttributes.html) to add them.

You can set [custom data with AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sns/set-endpoint-attributes.html) as follows:

```
$ aws sns set-endpoint-attributes --endpoint-arn arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:01234567890:endpoint/GCM/AppName/fc1397a1-7762-3061-adbc-ab92990038f8 --attributes "CustomUserData=user1@abc.com"
```

Comment: I saw the custom data option but was not able to comprehend how to publish a message with that as a filter. I looked into the aws console UI to publish and it just has option to select Topic. Reading you post it appears that I can do that. But still not sure how can I send the push message to endpoints with customuserdata as 'user1@abc.com'. Does the publish to topic arn with custom message attribute set and all users devices subscribe to that topic, will this work?

Comment: @AbhijitKadam were you able to make this filter happen? I'm stuck with the same problem, and our user base are at least 10k users. So making one request per user and manually check userdata is not an option.